# Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in php_serial.class.php on line 127

Tags: php, port

I was tried to communicate with serial port using php, my code is,

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ?>
<?php
include "php_serial.class.php";
use phpSerial\phpSerial;
$serial = new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");
$serial->confBaudRate(2400);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage("Hello !");
$read = $serial->readPort();
$serial->deviceClose();
$serial->confBaudRate(2400);
```

is i needed to include my php_serial.class.php in my question ? what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you running this code on Windows? Is the COM1 serial port present in the system?

Comment: i'm working on linux, how i can check com1 serial port present in the system?

Answer (score 2):

If you work on linux, you must use a different device:

```
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyS0"); // or /dev/ttyS1, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even when you enter the serial port correctly, you might get this error on Linux. In this case, you should give permission to read this port in the terminal by entering `sudo chmod 0777 /dev/YOUR_SERIAL_PORT` wich `YOUR_SERIAL_PORT` is your serial port, for example: `ttyS0`.
Also, don't forget to enter `sudo usermod -a -G dialout www-data` to grant PHP to use the serial port.